# an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format in ABCPDF

Tags: c#, .net, iis, dll, abcpdf

Im Using ABCPDF.net version 5.0 in my development server and it works fine without any issue.
Development Server Configuration:
OS: Windows Server 2003 32 bit 
iis 6.0

Production Server Configuration:
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit Operations System
iis7.5

The PDF option works fine in Development Server. But when i move the code to our production Server it is giving the following error

an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
Exception Code : 0*8007000b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the IIS Manager (inetmgr.msc), find the app pool controling your application, and go to Advanced properties. flip "Enable 32bit Applications" to True. that should do ya. consider creating a new app pool for this purpose if the one you have is shared by multiple applications.

Comment: Thanks for ur guidence. I already tried but to fetch the data i've to use IBMDB2 when i change the application Pool settings the DB2 connection is not working. Both are in same page so i was not able to use another application pool

Comment: have you tried compiling against a 32bit version of the IBM libraries

Comment: Can u pls explain the same in detail. im not familier with it.

Comment: well, you just download a 32bit version of whatever DB2 library you are using, remove the reference to the 64bit version you currently have, create a new reference to the new 32bit dll, and recompile.

Comment: Im Sorry i was on leave due to emergency. The Problem is that my development server is 32 bit server and my Production server is 64 bit. I installed 64 bit db2 in production server which works fine if i dont **enable 32 bit application** in production server but when i  enable that im getting this error. can u pls help me to fix this issue.

Comment: in that case, you will have to get a 64bit version of ABCPDF.net hope you can drop the libraries in the bin on the production site while running in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run 32bit components in a 32bit app pool, or ensure that when you publish to a 64bit machine you use 64bit components.